# Xcode Interface Builder resizing elements annoyingly

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, interface-builder

Interface Builder often resizes and replaces elements from my app. It does it when I load Interface Builder after launching Xcode. How can I prevent it from doing this? This bug messes things up really annoyingly. For instance the cells from tableviews are 1000 points in width and I can't resize back to screen width. Its subviews are also influenced. I have to delete the old cell and put in a new one.

Comment: This is because of a change in iOS 10 and Xcode 8. It is actually revealing a previously hidden issue with your views not being appropriately constrained to the view width. Fix your constraints and the issue will go away.

Comment: So this isn't a bug?

Comment: Some may say it falls in to the "it's not a bug its a feature" area. It is a change and I believe it is intentional on Apples part, it just seems that it wasn't very well publicised.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 8.0?

If yes, then please move to Xcode 8.1, as many things have been fixed in Xcode 8.1